# How does one magnetic field effect another

Tags: magnetic-fields

Do the fields cancel or are they additive or something else. Can we direct and focus them and or amplify then with similar fields? Can we eliminate the electric portion of an electromagnetic field?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Biot-Savart law?

Comment: The strength of the B field is proportional to the charge density of the electric field? But what if it is a permanent magnet with no electric field per se. How do the fields interact.

Comment: The magnetic field is not proportional to "the charge density of the electric field."  The Biot-Savart law to which Kyle eluded is a general expression for determining the magnetic field at arbitrary locations from a given source (i.e., electric currents, not charges).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magnetic fields add using vector addition. That is if at some point $\mathbf{r}$ you have a field $\mathbf{B}_1(\mathbf{r})$ and you introduce another magnetic field $\mathbf{B}_2(\mathbf{r})$ then the total field is just the vector sum of the two:

$$ \mathbf{B} = \mathbf{B}_1 + \mathbf{B}_2 $$

Comment: Is there a way to pulse and focus a magnetic wave?